# How to limit random image location to inside of another image

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have an HTML button and a JavaScript randomizer that randomizes a location for an image to 'spawn' when you click the said button. I also have a grass field image (which has a randomizer to choose from 12 different fields upon reloading the page and display one of them). Currently, it can 'spawn' an image anywhere on the page, however, I want it to only be able to spawn it onto the field.

my javascript:

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;
  
  // set the position
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.top = document.body.clientHeight * Math.random() + 'px';
  img.style.left = document.body.clientWidth * Math.random() + 'px';

  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', () =>
  show_image("cow-sprites/cowtest.png", 56, 54, 'foo')
);
```

my html:

```
<button id="foo">
    get a cow
</button>
```

my css:

```
.cow-spawning {
    z-index: 1;
}

.field-image {
    position: fixed;
    left: 28.25%;
    top: 16%;
    z-index: -1;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.85);
    -o-transform: scale(0.85);
    transform: scale(0.85);
}
```

what i've tried:

replacing

```
  img.style.top = document.body.clientHeight * Math.random() + 'px';
  img.style.left = document.body.clientWidth * Math.random() + 'px';
```

with

```
  img.style.top = meadows.naturalHeight * Math.random() + meadows_box.top + 'px';
  img.style.top = meadows.naturalHeight * Math.random() + meadows_box.left + 'px';
```

and creating a variable to hold the field image (meadows)

Comment: What if you wrap your field image in a div? Then all you need is to insert a new cow image in that parent div element with a random position from 0% to 100% (perhaps also account for the width/height of the cow image). Also, when you apply `scale` of <1 on your field, it will not be 100% of its actual size, and so when placing images  on the extreme left/right/top/botton they will appear to be outside of bounds.

Comment: The 2nd line is your last snippet should at least be img.style.left = meadows.naturalWidth * Math.random) + meadows_box.left + 'px';
Current it is resetting top using the height and the left position.

Answer (score 0):

You have the coordinates for a container (the field) and another box (the image). Each has a left (x) and top (y) position, as well as a width (x) and height (y).

You want to randomize the coordinates for the image so that all 4 corners of that image are inside the outer containers bounds. It can be difficult to think about positioning all 4 corners at once, but we can simplify the problem.

Let's only think of the left,top (x,y) coordinate. If the image stays within the container, then the lowest the top can be is the same as the bottom position of the container plus the height of the image. Similarly, the furthest right the image can go is one image width from the right side of the container.

For example, let's assume the outer container left,top is 0,0, and its width,height are 100,100. The inner image width,height is 10,10. The inner image can be at 0,0 inside the container extending to 10,10, which is the leftmost and topmost position. If the image is in the furthest bottom, right corner, then the bottom right coordinate is at 100,100. Since the image is 10,10 then the top,left corner is at 90,90.

In the end, this just tells us to calculate the random position using a reduced range.  Instead of being able to put the top or left coordinate anywhere from 0-100, we need to restrict them to 0-90, allowing for the image height and width padding it on the right and bottom.

```
img.style.top = (containerHeight - imageHeight) * Math.random() + 'px';
img.style.left = (containerWidth - imageWidth) * Math.random() + 'px';
```

Where containerHeight and containerWidth are the outer container height at width, assuming that the containerTop and containerLeft are both 0.  If you have to account for the offset position of the outer container, then we can account for that as well.

```
img.style.top = ((containerHeight - containerTop - imageHeight) * Math.random() + containerTop) + 'px';
img.style.left = ((containerWidth - containerLeft - imageWidth) * Math.random() + containerLeft) + 'px';
```

For example:

- containerLeft: 100
- containerTop: 200
- containerWidth: 100
- containerHeight: 200
- imageWidth: 10
- imageHeight: 20

Randomized left/X positions can range from 100 to 190 and the new top/Y position ranges can be from 200 to 280.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. to be clear, do I have  to replace containerHeight, containerWidth, etc., or just define it somewhere else, because as it stands, replacing it with that does not work
also, sorry for my late reply.

Comment: I would suggest defining those variables and then using them in the calculations. 
const containerLeft = 100; // for example